# HTML noob trying to color in red the numbers in numbered list

Tags: html, html-lists

as title describes, I (a total noob who just started learning HTML) am trying to make my numbers in my ordered list appear red in a HTML page. I've found the code below at various sources but it doesn't work so I must be missing something but I don't know what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul  {
list-style: none;
}

ul li::before {
content: counter(mycounter);
counter-increment: mycounter;
color: red;
display: inline-block; 
width: 1em;
margin-left: -1em;
}
</style>
```

I pledge myself to the knowledge of any and all masters of this dark art, thank you.

Comment: Post your HTML as well please. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your code shows the styling for a ul, meaning an unordnered list aka bullet points.
A better semantic would be to use a ordered list (ol) instead.

Then, we're going to remove the list style and add a counter instead to the ::before pseudo-element with `content: counter(li);`  which we then can style as wished. Lastly we have to increase the numbers, otherwise it will only show 0 in front of every list element.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none; 
  counter-reset: li;
}
li::before {
  content: counter(li); 
  color: red;
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em
}
li {
  counter-increment: li
}
```

Taken from: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html#numbers

Comment: thanks for your replies, it helped and I made it work however it caused a new problem. Inside my numbered list, there is a lettered list <ol type=a>. Applying the suggested code transformed the lettered list into a numbered list. I'd like the color red to be applied to the lettered list without changing it into a numbered list. what I don't know is will it need an entire new li::before pseudo-element to forcibly keep the lettered list littered, or can I add some code to that effect in the already existing li::before ?

Comment: Target the nested ol with a child selector. Change the value counter-style of the counter to "lower-alpha". Voilà

```css
ol > ol li::before {
 content: counter(li, lower-alpha);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of a list with numbers in red.

You can edit it and customize it to get the desired code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Red List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        ol {
            list-style: none;
            counter-reset: li
        }

        li::before {
            content: counter(li);
            color: red;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1em;
        }
        li {
            counter-increment: li
        }
    </style>
    <ol>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```